# pandoc md to pdf ,the ordered list to enumerate cause error Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: pandoc, markdown

Here is a markdown file

```
1. A
2. B
3. C
```

use `pandoc -i test.md -o test.pdf` to convert to pdf. But got an Error:
`Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`
use `pandoc -i test.md -o test.tex` to convert to tex. The tex file is

```
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\tightlist
\item
  A
\item
  B
\item
  C
\end{enumerate}
```

Then use `latex test.tex`,get the same error.
If I deleted the `[<+->]`,then use `latex test.tex`,can got the correct pdf.

What's more strangely ,When I use VSCode pandoc extension to render the md,It works correctly.
I want to know why and how to handle it.

Comment: As long as this is not a beamer document, that `[...] ` is definitely wrong. Is this the entire generated latex file? As that sniplet will never compile with latex no matter what (no preamble, document class etc) also where does that def come from?

Comment: You can try the standalone mode of pandoc, see if it works and then look at the generated document for further includes.

Comment: I got the reason.The `-i` cause the error.see https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1264 and
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5072